# How to automate gluonfx:runagent

Tags: java, javafx, graalvm, testfx, gluonfx

I'm working on a JavaFX/GluonFX project and consistently forget to update **gluonfx:runagent** for JSON reflection. To address this, I've implemented [TestFXs](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific/blob/main/src/test/java/com/mascix/swaggerific/SwaggerGuiTest.java) for UI testing and functionality checks.

What is the best way to automate runagent step ?

Reference: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_gluonfxrunagent